# MySQL starts, then stops, with error MY-013236, designated data directory /usr/local/mysql-8.0.18-macos10.14-x86_64/data/ is unusable

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm on a macOS, Apache, MySQL, PHP stack, and just installed MySQL 8.0.18 yesterday. It was up and running, I was creating schemas, and transacting with the localhost:3306 DB. Great!

Today, the server won't startup. I changed nothing overnight, no updates. In System Preferences -> MySQL, I click start, go green for a second, then flips back to red. From the terminal, I get the following (when using "mysqld --initialize"):

```
2019-11-06T20:39:22.399042Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.18-macos10.14-x86_64/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) initializing of server in progress as process 5705

2019-11-06T20:39:22.401472Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.

2019-11-06T20:39:22.401484Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /usr/local/mysql-8.0.18-macos10.14-x86_64/data/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2019-11-06T20:39:22.401543Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

2019-11-06T20:39:22.401726Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.18-macos10.14-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I've reviewed other posts suggesting adding the _mysql user as privileged user for the folder(s) in question, but it didn't work as shown:

```sh
sudo chown -R u+rwX,g+rwX,o-rwx /usr/local/mysql
chown:u+rwX,g+rwX,o-rwx: illegal user name
```

Can anyone help me get back to where I was yesterday? LOL?! Thanks!

Comment: looks like we are confusing the `chmod` and `chown` commands. (The arguments shown look like arguments to `chmod`).   Data directory only needs to be initialized one time, the behavior observed with `--initialize` on a non-empty directory is what we expect; its a failsafe mechanism, so that `--initialize` doesn't ever inadvertently corrupt/overwrite the data directory. (Running `--initialize` is an installation task, not part of normal startup/shutdown.)

Comment: Thanks Spencer. I scrapped the install and reinstalled. However, same problem (MySQL server won't stay started). This is MySQL 8.0.18 on MacOS Mojave (10.14). Any ideas?

Comment: i would start with checking the mysql error log, should be in the mysql data directory, file will be named  hostname.err    - problem could be any number of things, something as simple as an invalid entry in  my.cnf

Comment: according the error messages posted here, mysql thinks the data directory is `/usr/local/mysql-8.0.18-macos10.14-x86_64/data/`   that should contain the error log file